# How to define custom CSS within the document?

Tags: r, rstudio, rpres

According to the [RStudio documentation of RPres](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532307-Customizing-Fonts-and-Appearance), there's a way to add some custom CSS styles within the .Rpres document:

> [I]f you prefer to include styles right within the presentation source file you can also place them at the top of the source above the title slide (any style tags included there will automatically be appended to the head element).

Am I misunderstanding something? The following should work according to that:

```
.reveal section del {
  color: red;
}

test
========================================================

test
========================================================

~~should be red~~
```

But this produces:

[image: Screenshot of the rendered document. The first line reads ".reveal section del { color: red;}". The second line is indented and reads "test". The third line is at the same level of indentation as the second and reads "should be red" in grey; the 2nd line was in black.]

Clearly, it's not being parsed as CSS. Am I missing something?

If I simply save that section separately into a like-named .css file (as mentioned is possible in the same document), it works as expected. I just don't see the point in creating a separate file do define one single custom style.

Comment: You would still need `<style>` tags around the CSS I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style needs to be wrapped in `<style></style>`

```
<style>
.reveal section del{
  color: red;
}
</style>

csstest
========================================================
author: 
date: 
autosize: true


test
========================================================

~~should be red~~
```

[image]

I found [this presentation](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/27777_55697c3a476640caa0ad2099fe914ae5.html#/) to be a useful resource

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding the documentation to be a bit sparse. My CSS knowledge is 0 so even a small thing like this can throw me off still